# Average all columns in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have a Pig relation of which I want to calculate the average for all of its columns. Pig's buitin AVG()-function only works on one single column. This would not have been a problem in case my relation would have existed of only a few columns, in which case one could write something like the following:

```
MY_RELATION_AVERAGED = foreach MY_RELATION generate AVG($1), AVG($2), ...;
```

So to be clear here, what I want to end up with is the average over all tuples for each of my columns, not the average of my columns per tuple (which is the other way around). My relation however has tens of columns which makes the above solution not so elegant. Another solution would be to write a UDF for this, but it seems to me like there should be a more generic and elegant approach for such a simple task. Is my instinct correct here? Or is a UDF the way to go here?

Edit: Removed a slight ambiguity from the formulation of my question.

Comment: Probably you will need a UDF. Can you give an example of how you would program this in another language? It strikes me that you might be asking Pig to read your mind a bit too much in terms of knowing what you want to do with each column.

Comment: Can you given and example of the data and the schema, I feel like either I am missing something from your question or you are misunderstanding how AVG works.  It does not work over columns per se.